# How large can the array passed to SQL where column_value IN (Array) be?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, relational-database

I am writing some code that will lookup for unique id's in a table with over 60,000 rows for the ones that are in an array using

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE  unique_indexed_user_id IN('".join("', '", $array)."')") ;
```

the amount of this array is not limited to the end user so they might end up selecting a large array. thus I have to limit the  array

```
   if( count($array_limit)>$array_limit ) 
  array_splice($array, $array_limit);
```

but I have no idea how to figure out the limit, this code is being used in a social network for people to invite their friends to something. so the bigger it is the better. however I don't know how big of an array mysql can handle?

what should the value of `$array_limit` be?

Comment: I think the limit is determined by the size in bytes of the query, rather than the number of elements in the array. The limit on the size of the query is determined by max_packet_size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The max length of a query passed to MySQL is the length of your `max_packet_size` variable.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html

You also might want to take other things into consideration, such as the length of time it will take to parse and execute a query with that many IDs.  I've taken this approach myself, and it started to seriously slow down after a few thousand IDs.  You may want to try a `JOIN`, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

How many do you need, really?

I have used something like 10000 items in a query without problem (while moving data from one database to another, not in a live site), so you can certainly make a horribly big query.

There is however no point in getting that many items when you want to display them to a user, because noone scrolls through a list that large to the end, and having that much data would most likely slow down the user interface considerably.

You should use some kind of paging or append on request, so that you only get something like a hundred items each time.